# SQL Server достать названия колонок по одной зная название таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Собственно вопрос в названии нужно вытащить по одной названия колонок используя Sys Schema. К примеру я составил запрос на извлечение названия всех колонок по одной

```html
SELECT name  FROM DB.sys.columns order by name OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

где DB -название моей базы данных. Как мне вставить правильно условие WHERE чтобы указать название определенной таблицы. Пробовал по всякому что то не отдает.
Запросы через information schema не подойдет к примеру такой

```html
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'Имя таблицы' ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы, надеюсь понятно описал вопрос.

Comment: `where sys.columns.object_id = OBJECT_ID('db.schema.table_name')` ?

Comment: Что то не работает

Comment: почитайте документацию, что там в параметрах точно указывается. наверное просто схема и имя

Comment: Да что то не так у меня с object_id только пока не понимаю что)спасибо